# Help with Objective-C variable declaration syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Is there a difference between these two declarations?  Is one better practice?

- NSString* hello = @"HelloWorld";
- NSString *hello = @"HelloWorld";

Thanks--

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference, although the second one I find is more popular amongst Objective-C developers.

Answer (score 3):

dreamlax's answer is correct but I would like to make the things more clear, the compiler strips whitespaces, both examples will be converted to NSString*hello=@"HelloWorld"; so there is no difference at all, use the one you feel more comfortable with. I prefer the second one, because its more clear (I read all declarations from right to left):

```
NSString *hello = @"HelloWorld";
^        ^        ^
3        2        1
```

1 => We have string value
2 => Pointer variable pointing to the address in memory where our object value is stored
3 => Object is of type NSString

(:

Comment: Appreciate the clarification- I prefer the second as well- It makes sense when broken down syntactically, as you illustrated.